# Square items for AutoFitRecyclerView grid

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a grid implementation of the recyclerview using the Autofit grid as detailed here:

http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-autofit-grid.html

However, my grid items are not squares (they are rectangles) despite fixing the grid item size. Is there a way to make the items square (as in actual `GridView`) while maintaining the autofit property

**item_grid_image.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
         android:id="@+id/image_wrapper"
         android:layout_width="140dp"
         android:layout_height="140dp"
         android:padding="1dp"
         android:layout_centerInParent="true">

    <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        tools:src="@drawable/file_directory" /> 

</FrameLayout>
```

**fragment_recyclerview.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/grid_view_wrapper"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_margin"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <com.project.AutoFitRecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/grid_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/count_text_view"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:columnWidth="140dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_grid_image">
        </com.project.AutoFitRecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the reason for this is that it is very rare that your `RecyclerView` would have a width that is divisible by your `columnWidth` property. That means that your actual column width will almost always be larger than 140dp while the cell  height will always be 140dp.

To fix this, you need to make your image match the column width and make the height match the width. One way to accomplish this would be to use a [SquareFrameLayout](https://developer.android.com/samples/ActivitySceneTransitionBasic/src/com.example.android.activityscenetransitionbasic/SquareFrameLayout.html):

```
<com.project.SquareFrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/image_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="1dp">

    <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        tools:src="@drawable/file_directory" />

</com.project.SquareFrameLayout>
```

Comment: Great! `SquareFrameLayout` is the saviour